# Newton's method for fraction

Tags: approximation, newton-raphson, numerical-calculus

Let $a\gt0$. Start from a convenient equation and use Newton's method to deduce a method to approximate $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$ without divisions. How is the starting value chosen? What is the termination criteria? Deduce from here a method to approximate $\sqrt{a}$ without divisions.

Now I see that in the solution, they start from the equation $f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{x^2}-a=0$ for which they apply Newton's method. Why is this the equation? I don't understand the reasoning behind it.

Also, they say that any value $x_0\gt0$ can be chosen as a starting value. I don't really understand this either. What about the $\sqrt{a}$ part?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How would you use NM to find the square root of a problem, see: https://math.mit.edu/~stevenj/18.335/newton-sqrt.pdf? This is analogous to your problem.

Comment: See section 3.1: https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_12/papers/ben.pdf and also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Iterative_methods_for_reciprocal_square_roots,